# Extraneous HTML in doxygen

Tags: whitespace, doxygen

I'm trying to import a code snippet into HTML using doxygen. The code snippet is a few lines long and I've preformatted it using <pre> tags. However, when the HTML is generated, doxygen is inserting

`<div class="line">`

before each line of my snippet. The result is the HTML is generated with extra space between each line of the code snippets. How do I get rid of this? I just want the code snippet in there with the pre-formatted whitespace.

This is with doxygen 1.8.1.1

Comment: Can you show us the documentation in which you are trying to include you HTML? When I simply include `<pre>Some text</pre>` into an existing documentation block I get exactly that in the doxygen output with no extra `div`s.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and reported a bug against DoxyGen. See link: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=681135

The answer is quick and simple: The "line" class has been added quite recently and it takes an update of the custom CSS files. In my case the resolution was simple:

- Open the project in DoxyWizard
- Go to "Expert" view and configure HTML output
- Remove the entry for your Custom CSS
- run DoxyWizard once
- Copy the div.line and div.line.glow definitions from default CSS into your custom CSS and modify as desired
- Be happy

HTH, Nick

Comment: The default stylesheet does have a definition for the "line" class, since revision 814, see http://doxygen.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/doxygen/trunk/src/doxygen.css?view=log part of releases 1.8.1.1 and 1.8.1.2. Please make sure you are not using a custom stylesheet that requires updating...